# JavaScript Adding Method Conditionally

Tags: javascript, function, methods

I am reading "JavaScript: The Good Parts" and have come across this confusing code snip-it

```
 Function.prototype.method = function( name, func){
    if (!this.prototype[name]){
        this.prototype[name] = func;
    }
};
```

The book says "One defensive technique is to add a method only if the method is known to be missing." The question i have regarding this are:

- how does this code snip-it work?
- how would i use this method we created
- why is it "this.prototype" and not "this.method" or "this.name"

Thank you for your time